# How to get the latest version number from a sql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table and it contain the list of version number, how to get the latest version number ?

| id | Version number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.1.0 |
| 2 | 1.2.1 |
| 3 | 1.1.3 |

how will i get the latest version '2.1.0' from the table by executing a sql query.

Comment: I've gone ahead and remove the conflicting tags. [Edit] your question to tag correctly.

Comment: it is postgres sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres you can convert the version number to an integer array, then use the `max()` function:

```
select max(string_to_array(version_number, '.')::int[])
from the_table;
```

Alternatively if you want the whole row, you can use:

```
select *
from the_table
order by string_to_array(version_number, '.')::int[] desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: so what will it convert '2.1.0' to ?

Comment: @tryingToCode: an integer array (`int[]`) as I wrote.

Comment: if the version is '3.0.1' and '2.0.12' which will be max?

Comment: @tryingToCode: obviously 3.0.1